# NSManagedObjectContext's performBlockAndWait: not executing on the receiver's queue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I've noticed that it's possible for an `NSManagedObjectContext` with an `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` to `performBlockAndWait`: and execute the block on a queue other than the receiver's (main) queue.

For example, the following code results in my `parentContext` executing the block on the `childContext`'s queue if my `parentContext` is of type `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and my `childContext` is of type `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`:

```
[childContext performBlockAndWait:^{
    //Thread 1, Queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue
    [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        //Thread 1, Queue: NSManagedObjectContext Queue
        //This is the same queue as the child context's queue
    }];
}];
```

In contrast, the following code works as expected – my `parentContext` executes the block on the main queue:

```
[childContext performBlock:^{
    [parentContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        //Thread 1, Queue: com.apple.main-thread
    }];
}];
```

Is this the expected behavior? It is certainly confusing me since the docs state `"performBlockAndWait: synchronously performs a given block on the receiver’s queue."`

Comment: How are you checking to see what queue the code runs on?

Answer (score 3):

You should not be worried on what thread blocks are executed. What the `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` methods guarantee is **thread safety**. Thus, calling `performBlockAndWait:` from the main thread does not mean there would be a context switch to a background thread - it is very expensive and it is not needed. If during the operation of the block (on the main thread), an attempt is performed to perform a block, it would be blocked until the currently executing block is finished. At the end of the day, the result would be the same as if a context switch was performed, only faster. On the other hand, calling `performBlock:` will queue the block on an arbitrary queue, often executing on a background thread.

In the example above, since you `performBlockAndWait:`, your private queue context executes your block on the main thread, as does the main context block. In your second example, you schedule the block to run asynchronously, so it is executed on a background thread.

You should not judge a thread's queue by it's name. To see if you are on the main queue, you can use `dispatch_get_current_queue()` and test if it is equal to `dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

Comment: This kind if behavior is why dispatch_get_current_queue is deprecated. Basically, if you think you care about the identity of the queue you're on, you're probably doing something wrong, because there isn't always one right answer.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Do your code right and there will be no problems.

Comment: This does not really answer my question. To clarify, my question is: Why does an `NSManagedObjectContext` with an `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` execute the block from `performBlockAndWait:` on any queue other than the main queue when the docs state: `"performBlockAndWait: synchronously performs a given block on the receiver’s queue."` In this case, the receiver's queue should be the main queue. I have verified that it is not always the main queue, as shown above.

Comment: There could be a documentation issue, and you should file a bug report for documentation improvement. `performBlockAndWait:` does not perform the context switch of moving to a different thread, thus executing on another queue. Why does it bother you if it keeps thread safety. You can still be sure that it will execute on the main thread.

Comment: I guess if I use a single MOC with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` I should ALWAYS use `performBlock` or `performBlockAndWait` but looks like I can access it to read and write also from the main thread without using those blocks :S