# NSManagedObjectContext: performBlockAndWait vs performBlock with notification center

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsnotificationcenter

I came across intriguing behaviour when using *NSManagedObjectContext*'s `performBlock:` with notification center.

From the main UI thread I trigger asynchronous data download (using *NSURLConnection*'s `connectionWithRequest:`). When data arrive the following delegate method is called:

```
- (void)downloadCompleted:(NSData *)data
{
    NSArray *new_data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

    self.backgroundObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc]   
                          initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.backgroundObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;

    [self.backgroundObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self saveToCoreData:new_data];
    }];
}
```

The `savetoCoreData:` method is simply saving new data to the background context:

```
- (void)saveToCoreData:(NSArray*)questionsArray
{
    for (NSDictionary *questionDictionaryObject in questionsArray) {
        Question *newQuestion = [NSEntityDescription 
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Question" 
                               inManagedObjectContext:self.backgroundObjectContext];

        newQuestion.content = [questionDictionaryObject objectForKey:@"content"];            
    }

    NSError *savingError = nil;
    [self.backgroundObjectContext save:&savingError];
}
```

In the view controller, in `viewDidLoad` I add observer to the notification center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(contextChanged:) 
                                             name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And then in the `contexChanged:` I merge the background context with the main context so that my NSFetchedResultsController's delegate methods are called where my view can be updated:

```
- (void)contextChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification object] == self.managedObjectContext) return;

    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

It all seems to work well, but there is one thing that bothers me. When in `downloadCompleted:` method I use `performBlock:` instead of `performBlockAndWait:` the notification seems to be delayed. It takes noticeable (around 5s) amount of time from the moment the background thread does `save:` till the moment *NSFetchedResultsController* calls its delegate. When I use `performBlockAndWait:` I do not observe any visible delay - the delegate is called as fast as if I called `saveToCoreData:` inside `_dispatch_async_`.

Does anyone saw that before and know if this is normal or am I abusing something?

Comment: Note that the notification is raised on the background thread, and you merge changes to the main context in a background thread which is very ill advised. use `[self.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:...]`

Comment: That indeed makes perfect sense. Thanks Dan! I did not realise that `connectionWithRequest:` calls the delegate methods on "(...) the thread that started the asynchronous load operation for the associated NSURLConnection object." This can be easily observed by checking `[NSThread isMainThread]`.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Dan in one of the comments, the merge operation should happen on the main thread. This can be easily observed by changing the `contextChanged:` method to do the following:

```
 - (void)contextChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification object] == self.managedObjectContext) return;

    if (![NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(contextChanged:) 
                               withObject:notification 
                            waitUntilDone:YES];
        return;
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
}
```

With this change, both `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` are working.

As long as this explains to some extent why the problems were occurring in the first place, I still do not understand why `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` perform differently from the threading perspective. Apple documentation says:

> `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` ensure the block operations are executed on the queue specified for the context. The `performBlock:` method returns immediately and the context executes the block methods on its own thread. With the `performBlockAndWait:` method, the context still executes the block methods **on its own thread**, but the method doesn’t return until the block is executed.

This indicates, that if the true root cause of the problem described in the question is that merging is happening in the background thread, then I should observe identical behaviour regardless of which method I am calling: `performBlock:` and `performBlockAndWait:` - both are executing in a sperate thread.

As a side note, since the `NSURLConnection` calls the delegate method on the same thread that started the asynchronous load operation - main thread in my case - using background context seems to be not necessary at all. `NSURLConnections` deliver its events in the run loop anyway.

Comment: I believe that last sentence of Apple's documentation is incorrect.

Comment: I believe that last sentence is correct. I ran into this subtle distinction recently while testing with `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`. This answer explains it nicely:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/19439817/140799